# Trim the last digit only if numeric entered.

Tags: javascript

```
     applicantAddressZipCode.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue != undefined && newValue != '') {

        applicantAddressZipCode(formatZipCode(newValue));
        var dataValue = String(applicantAddressZipCode().replace(/[^\/\d]/g, ''));
        if (dataValue > 9999999999999.99 || dataValue < 0) {
            applicantAddressZipCode('');
        }

        if (loading == false) {
            sendCommand('SAVE');
        }
    }
});



function formatZipCode(value) {

    value = value.replace(/[^\/\d]/g, '');
    var z = /(\d{5})-?(\d{4})/
    if (value != undefined && value != '') {
        return value = value.replace(z, "$1-$2")
    }


    else {
        return value;
    }
};
```

I have created a function for zipcode inputs. The function works perfectly fine if user enters 12345-6789 and also 12-3456789 would result to 12345-6789. My problem is when user enters only numbers such as 1234567890, the function would go to 12345-67890. I would like to create a function to trim/slice the last digit when ONLY in the case numbers entered with out the hyphen. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you please show the expected output

Comment: If you can Call like this means **formatZipCode("1234567890")** your code will be perfectly working.. the parameter value will be have to use string variable because **value.replace** code is work only string..

Comment: @brk  thank you for your help in advance. I would like to enter 10 digits inputs, numbers only, and the out put would be 9 digits. Basiclly cut the last digit! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be another option as zip code is always 9 digit number.

```
 if (value != undefined && value != '') {
        value = value.replace(z, "$1-$2")
        if(value.length>10){
          value = value.substring(0,10)
          return value
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you fo your help. This did not work as it made  applicantAddressZipCode(...) undfined. I think because of this if (dataValue > 9999999999999.99 || dataValue < 0) {
            applicantAddressZipCode('');
        }

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to check that number do not contain a hyphen. Use this line of code to check that. If there is no hyphen in the input number then the index of hyphen will be -1.

   ```
   if(inputValue.indexOf('-') == -1){
       //input do not contain hyphen so remove the last character
   }
   ```
2. Then you need to call a another function or code that will trim you the last character from the output you receive as 12345-67890.

   ```
   tempOutput.slice(0,-1);
   //where tempOutput contains the temporary output 12345-67890
   ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, but can you tell me where i should put this exactly in my code? Thankss in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` and `slice()` to remove the last element of the string:

```js
function formatZipCode(value) {

  value = value.replace(/[^\/\d]/g, '');
  var z = /(\d{5})-?(\d{4})/
  if (value != undefined && value != '') {
    value = value.replace(z, "$1-$2");
    value = value.split('-');
    if (value[1].length >= 5) {
      return value = value[0] + "-" + value[1].slice(0, 4)
    }
  } else {
    return value;
  }
};

var zip = formatZipCode("1234567890");
console.log(zip);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. This did not work as it made applicantAddressZipCode(...) undfined. I think because of this if (dataValue > 9999999999999.99 || dataValue < 0) { applicantAddressZipCode(''); }

Comment: @AbdullahAlShammari Well `applicantAddressZipCode()` doesn't have to do anything in the code with `formatZipCode()` as both are different functions.